# Show that $fg$ is differentiable at $\hat{x}$ and that $(fg)'(\hat{x})= g(\hat{x})f'(\hat{x}) + f(\hat{x})g'(\hat{x})$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $U$ an open set in $\mathbb{R^n}$, $\hat{x} \in U$ and let $f : U
>  \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g : U \to \mathbb{R}$ two different
>   differentiable functions at $\hat{x}$. Show that $fg$ is
>   differentiable at $\hat{x}$ and that $(fg)'(\hat{x})=
>  g(\hat{x})f'(\hat{x}) + f(\hat{x})g'(\hat{x})$.

I know basically the proof for two functions at one variable. However, the problem seems to be different when we have two functions with strictly more than one variable. I don't know why but I tried different things and I don't have the flash to finish this problem. So that's what I've done so far:

We have $$\lim_{x \to \hat{x}} \frac{f(x)-f(\hat{x})-f'(\hat{x})(x-\hat{x})}{||x-\hat{x}||}$$ and $$\lim_{x \to \hat{x}} \frac{g(x)-g(\hat{x})-g'(\hat{x})(x-\hat{x})}{||x-\hat{x}||}$$

Let $h(x)=(fg)(x)$ and taken $h'(\hat{x}) = g(\hat{x})f'(\hat{x}) + f(\hat{x})g'(\hat{x})$.

Then $$\lim_{x \to \hat{x}} \frac{h(x)-h(\hat{x})-h'(\hat{x})(x-\hat{x})}{||x-\hat{x}||} = \lim_{x \to \hat{x}} \frac{(fg)(x)-(fg)(\hat{x})-(g(\hat{x})f'(\hat{x}) + f(\hat{x})g'(\hat{x}))(x-\hat{x})}{||x-\hat{x}||}$$

From this time, I tried differents factorizations, but it block; here one of them : $$(fg)(x)-(fg)(\hat{x}) = f(x)(g(x) - g(\hat{x})) + g(\hat{x})(f(x)-f(\hat{x}))$$ and $$g(\hat{x})f'(\hat{x}) + f(\hat{x})g'(\hat{x}) = f(\hat{x})(g(\hat{x})- g'(\hat{x})) + g'(\hat{x})(f(\hat{x}) + f'(\hat{x}))$$

Does someone could tell me where I could make a correction? Otherwise, is there an easier way to approach this type of question?

Comment: @AhmedHussein, actually, a linear function.

Answer (score 2):

The idea: if
$$f(x)\approx f(\hat x) + f'(\hat x)(x-\hat x)\qquad\text{and}\qquad g(x)\approx g(\hat x) + g'(\hat x)(x-\hat x)$$
then
$$f(x)g(x)\approx f(\hat x)g(\hat x) + g(\hat x)f'(\hat x)(x-\hat x) +
f(\hat x)g'(\hat x)(x-\hat x) + f'(\hat x)(x-\hat x)g'(\hat x)(x-\hat x)
$$
with the last term much smaller than the other terms.

EDIT: The good is your first idea:
$$
f(x)g(x)-f(\hat x)g(\hat x) =
f(x)g(x)- f(x)g(\hat x) + f(x)g(\hat x) - f(\hat x)g(\hat x) 
$$
$$
= f(x)(g(x) - g(\hat{x})) + g(\hat{x})(f(x)-f(\hat{x}))
$$
and use the continuity of $f$.

Comment: I understand, but It's a bit hard the play with the different limit. Is there exist a factorisation I could use in my problem?

Comment: How could I use the continuity here

Comment: @TajMohamedBandalandabad $f(x)\approx f(\hat x)$.